# ClickOnce DLL Deployment

Tags: c#, deployment, clickonce

Is it possible to have a ClickOnce deployment that only registers a DLL on the user's machine or can it only deploy WinForms/WPF applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClickOnce is all about installing programs without altering the configuration of the machine.  Even if you could deploy a DLL, nobody would be able to find it back.

Comment: Thanks. I figured this was the case but was looking for alternatives to a CAB deployment for an activex control.